# Adding extra metadata to a Microsoft "ILogger" LogDebug message?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, microsoft.extensions.logging

I have the following message I wish to log:

```
_logger.LogDebug("Finished: DB retrieved OutboundData settings.", new { ElapsedTime = stopwatch.Elapsed });
```

- this is using the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger interface
- notice how there is no variables in the string message? this is by design.
- notice how I've added some extra meta? this is to be added to the key/value stuff for the log message.

e.g.

[image]

see how this message has 4x extra key/values meta-data? That's awesome. I was hoping to add a 5th one ("ElapsedTime" / the actual value) to this single logging method.

Is this possible?

SIDE NOTE:

- I'm using Serilog as the final logging library
- Serilog is NOT any any of my projects except the host-project. So please do NOT suggest any serilog specific methods. That will not work.

Comment: https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/

Comment: Yep - I've known of that blog post for ages - i's a great post! I was hoping to avoid doing a single scope per log message. Was praying there might be some other trick.

Comment: Ultimately from the Serilog perspective, the Capture process is picking stuff up from Enrichers (e.g. the LogContext), and the Context dictionary. As MSEL doesn't have a way to build that context other than BeginScope, the only remaining route is to stash if for an Enricher to pick it up. If you're unwilling to reference Serilog, you won't have access to `LogContext.Push` so you can't win; Of course `LogContext.Push` and `BeginScope` aren't massively different in terms of beauty or cost

Comment: Correct - there is no chance I'll ever put serilog into any project that is -not- my host (webapi / console app). So I'm stuck with BeginScope, it seems :( I guess this means I'll need to make a number of extension methods?

Comment: I'm guessing so. It'd be great if MS could add something more elegant; perhaps adding your specific desires to the the undoubtedly already logged request to add it there might tip them over the edge. (My take is to just use Serilog in the app - mainly via the `static Log.`, but for instance I have [a library](https://github.com/jet/equinox) where I can't stomach the pain of converting to MSEL for this exact reason (not being able to add context without lots of extreme ugliness). Ultimately the answer there though is to emit OT traces instead of logs though...

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#log-scopes) to add all of your metadata to. For example:

```cs
using var scope = _logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>() { ["ElapsedTime"] = stopwatch.Elapsed });
_logger.LogDebug("Finished: DB retrieved OutboundData settings.");
```

Comment: but that scope will contain the elapsed time for any code _after_ it, also? I just wanted it for that SINGLE log entry. So this means I would need to create 4 lines of code for each log entry that will contain some data that's not in the log message template?

Comment: @Pure.Krome It will until you dispose of the scope, yeah. You could probably wrap it up in an extension method to simplify the usage of it.

Comment: I would have though this has been a well documented thing? at least the extension methods?

Comment: Scopes are documented (see the link in my answer). Re extension methods: I was suggesting that you could create your own, though I'm not sure it would actually help much.